# Tried to build a scala project with sbt. Unresolved dependency with scala-swing

Tags: java, swing, scala, sbt

I tried to compile a scala project with sbt. I downloaded the scala binary (2.11.2). The project can be cloned on github.

```
git clone git://github.com/scalation/scalation.git scalation
```

I moved the entire scala binary to the project root and modified the Build.sbt and here's my change.

```
name := "scalation"

scalaVersion := "2.11.2"

scalaHome := Some(file("scala-2.11.2"))

libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang" % "scala-swing" % "2.11-1.0.1"
```

I can see the project is being compiled with the correct binary but after a while it gives me the following error:

```
module not found: org.scala-lang.modules#scala-swing;2.11-1.0.1
```

And the version of the scala swing

```
~/scalation$ ls scala-2.11.2/lib/
scala-swing_2.11-1.0.1.jar
```

I think there's something wrong with my libraryDependencies.

Let me explain why I made the modification in `build.sbt`.
When I first cloned the project, I followed the instruction and do `./sbt compile`
It gives me

```
/home/pierre/scalation/src/scalation/process/Model.scala:11: not found: object actors
[error] import actors.Actor
```

Then I realized it cannot find my scala. So I added this line and dragged my scala binary to this project because it's more convenient.

```
scalaHome := Some(file("scala-2.11.2"))
```

And when I do ./sbt compile again, it goes through the previous error but gives me another one

```
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.scala-lang#scala-swing;2.11.2: not found
[error] Total time: 3 s, completed Aug 30, 2014 6:04:36 PM
```

[Updated Answer: INSTALLATION GUIDE]
In case someone happens to be interested in this project, the correct installation is here:
http://cobweb.cs.uga.edu/~jam/scalation_1.0/INSTALL_SBT.html

The one on github is broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you are trying to do with those modification, and I never thought you need to copy the whole scala binaries and sbt binaries into your project... but have you at least checked whether that version of scala-swing does exist?

Should it actually be

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang.modules" % "scala-swing_2.11" % "1.0.1"
```

or even

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-swing" % "1.0.1"
```

?

Comment: Just now I tried your answer. It passed the last error and gave me another one, but you solved my question, tho I still cannot build the project successfully. 
The Error: (compile:compile) Error compiling sbt component 'compiler-interface'

Comment: What kind of error? I am afraid that it is not very clear from your comment.

Comment: Please be aware that from 2.10 to 2.11 is a major version change in Scala, and some packages may have been moved out from the core scala library, and you may have issue from that.

Comment: Also, you should not have sbt and scala binaries in the project folder. If you use sbt, you don't even need to hava scala installed in your system at all. I strongly suggest you install sbt in your system. This will make the maintenance of your dev environment much easier in the future.